# My vba is not finding the last non blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I used this line of code to find the last row in Col A.

```
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

However, there are a total of 1500 data in col A, but it only detects 1107 of them. Why is it so?

I used Debug.Print(lastRow) to check and it shows 1107.

Comment: No repro. Can you add a screenshot including the data in row 1500?

Comment: I have added pic of row 1500

Comment: Are you sure `ActiveSheet` is the one you think it is? What does `Debug.Print IsEmpty(Range("A1500"))` return?

Comment: Ya. I believe so

Comment: You should test, e.g. `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name`.

Comment: Double check you don't have a blank at row 1107?

Comment: You are right, my code went to another sheet, which have a last row of 1107. I have edited my code. Thank you!